# Filter through Wordpress posts with Custom Taxonomies

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have custom taxonomies for my Wordpress blog posts. I would like to allow users to filter through them using AJAX. I've been able to call the full page and get the results that way, but my response includes all the HTML. I'm wondering if there is a way to filter through Wordpress posts via AJAX and get the resulting object returned?

This is currently what I have:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "&product_form="+product_form,
            url: "http://localhost/websites/test/products/?filer=true",
            success: function(results) {
                console.log(results);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to put some comment marks just before and after output of your posts in products/?filer=true and then split the resulting data based on this marks.

For example you put

```
<!--SPLITMARK-->
```

right before and after posts output, then you do the splitting with result in js:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "&product_form="+product_form,
        url: "http://localhost/websites/test/products/?filer=true",
        success: function(results) {
            results = results.split("<!--SPLITMARK-->");
            results = results[1];
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
```

Anyway that method is fast approach but kinda dirty...